# application is not showing the String in textView

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner to android studio. i created 2 activity and i want to send a string value from main activity to second activity and show the String inside the second activity. after many questions and problem resolving(force closing) , my application runs good. but it not shows(print) the String.

I want to recive a string by input and sent it to second activity and print it by setText(); Method.

> **Main Activity**

```
package com.ghermez.sibe.salary_usd;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.lang.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button B1 =  findViewById(R.id.button1);
     B1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        EditText et_tusd = findViewById(R.id.tusd);
        String textFromInput_tusd = et_tusd.getText().toString();

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("i1",textFromInput_tusd);

            startActivity(i);

        }



      });

    }

}
```

> **Second Activity**

```
package com.ghermez.sibe.salary_usd;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.lang.String;


public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Intent i1s = getIntent();
        TextView textViewTusd = findViewById(R.id.textViewTusd);
        String tusd = i1s.getStringExtra("i1");
        textViewTusd.setText(tusd);

    }
}
```

> LogCat

```
04-22 18:21:02.486 1690-1717/com.ghermez.sibe.salary_usd E/EGL_emulation: tid 1717: eglSurfaceAttrib(1210): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
04-22 18:21:15.970 1690-1717/com.ghermez.sibe.salary_usd E/EGL_emulation: tid 1717: eglSurfaceAttrib(1210): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
04-22 18:21:17.905 1690-1717/com.ghermez.sibe.salary_usd E/EGL_emulation: tid 1717: eglSurfaceAttrib(1210): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
04-22 18:21:21.557 1690-1717/com.ghermez.sibe.salary_usd E/EGL_emulation: tid 1717: eglSurfaceAttrib(1210): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
04-22 18:21:23.586 1690-1717/com.ghermez.sibe.salary_usd E/EGL_emulation: tid 1717: eglSurfaceAttrib(1210): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the string from the `EditText` once the `Button` is clicked.
You were initializing the variable when `onCreate` is called.

Try this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button B1 =  findViewById(R.id.button1);
    EditText et_tusd = findViewById(R.id.tusd);

    B1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String textFromInput_tusd = et_tusd.getText().toString();

            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("i1",textFromInput_tusd);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String textFromInput_tusd = et_tusd.getText().toString();
```

This assigns textFromInput_tusd to be the current value of the edit text.  It doesn't keep updating it.  Since you put that in onCreate, it will be assigned once in onCreate and never changed.  Put it in your onClick instead, so you get the most recent value when the button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code in MainActivity, Try this one

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.lang.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button B1 =  findViewById(R.id.button1);
EditText et_tusd = findViewById(R.id.tusd);
 B1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String textFromInput_tusd = et_tusd.getText().toString();
        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
        i.putExtra("i1",textFromInput_tusd);

        startActivity(i);

    }



  });

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did application similar what you want.

Here is first Activity:

```
package com.example.user_pc.abulab;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editText;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void buttonClick(View v){
    editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String username = editText.getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.example.user_pc.abulab.Next.class);
    intent.putExtra("username", username);

    startActivity(intent);

}
}
```

Here is second Activity:

```
package com.example.user_pc.abulab;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Next extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);

    String username2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

    textView.setText(username2);
}
}
```